# Is it possible to update the values in hashmap or add new elements when iterating over it?

Tags: hashmap

I have this hashmap, and I want to update the values when iterating over it, and if possible add new elements. I believe It will throw a concurrentmodification exception. So, is there a way to achieve this or it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know the best you can do is removing and updating values while cycling. Try the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("one", "lemon");
    map.put("two", "orange");
    map.put("three", "kiwi");

    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
    {

        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();

        String key = (String)entry.getKey();

        //removal
        if(key.equals("one"))
            it.remove();

        //update
        if(key.equals("two"))
            entry.setValue("lime");

    }
}
```

inserting a new element in the map will cause the exception. If you need to do so, you should fill a second HashMap with the values of the first, and modify it at will. In other words, you can build a second HashMap while cycling on the first, and so you can manage it with the needed flexibility.